# UIScrollView Infinite Scroll?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about creating an infinite scroll. A good example of this is in the 4 Track iPhone app. There are scrollable "wheels" above the track numbers and below the time indicator. I'm assuming it's using UIScrollView and then drawing the subview as they are scrolled into to view. Any tips?

[image]
<sub>(source: [3dbcreative.com](http://www.3dbcreative.com/uploads/wysiwygPro/imgs/4_track_app2.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't use a UIScrollView - I would just subclass UIView and deal with dragging myself, positioning the UIView subviews as the touch moved events occur.