# repeat an image when scrolling on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, loops, ios4, uiimageview

i've got an UIImageView, now i want to repeat this image, that it always shows up again when scrolling left or right.

Little Example:

[image]

is this possible? it should feel like an infinite loop

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710781/uiscrollview-infinite-scroll and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493950/uiscrollview-any-thoughts-on-implementing-infinite-scroll-zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "infinite" rules out a `UISCrollView` or a `CATiledLayer`, obviously.

I'd say the easiest way to achieve this is to initialize enough `UIImageView`s to completely fill your screen (or scroll area), plus one, and implement your own dragging/scrolling system and recycle the `UIImageView`s as they go off one side of the screen to reappear on the other side. Because all the `UIImageView`s are the same image you shouldn't ever have to worry about memory/cache management.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about performance, you can use a "pattern image":

```
UIView * backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:repeatingImage];
```

I think it just draws it to the view's context, though, which means it can't be "infinite" and performance might be a bit slow.

Comment: can background color image be made zoomable?